# half as much/many again as something

Tags: phrase-usage

Is **"half as much/many again as"** more popular in writing and speaking than **"1.5 times as much/many as"**?

Answer (score 3):

[*half as much again as* is much more common in writing than *1.5 times as much as*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=1.5+times+as+much+as%2Chalf+as+much+again+as&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=en-2012&smoothing=3)

The same is true in the comparison of the [*many* versions](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=1.5+times+as+many+as%2Chalf+as+many+again+as&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=en-2012&smoothing=3).

Conversations are not tracked in Google Books, and hence I can't show any objective results of comparison.

Comment: In fact, although there are just a handful of instances in Google Books for ["1.5 times as many votes"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%221.5+times+as+many+votes%22), there are an estimated 7 pages of matches for ["one and a half times as many votes"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22one+and+a+half+times+as+many+votes%22). I expected to find at least a few hits for "half as many again votes", but apparently that *never* occurs. But ["half as many votes again"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22half+as+many+votes+again%22) returns an estimated **9** pages of results.

Comment: ...so your NGram chart isn't really helpful, since what you *should* be comparing is *one and a half times as much as* - but that's far too many words for NGrams.

Comment: I thought it should be "half as many again as votes", shouldn't it?

Comment: @KenAdams "half as many again as votes" isn't grammatical for me, "half as many votes again" is the only clearly grammatical form for me with "half as many again votes" being tenuously acceptable in informal speech

Comment: I think "50% more than" would be even more common than either alternative.

Comment: Raw frequency is not how to decide which expression to use,  *1.5 times as many*, or *50% more than*, or *half again as many.* The style and tone of the prose is what  would govern the choice.

Comment: @TimR to throw a spanner in the works, I'd prefer "half as many again" over "half again as many" (without particular distinction, although as you say, style and tone would govern my choice between this and the other two)

Comment: @Tristan You would say "Basket B has half as many apples again as Basket A" ?

Comment: I'd definitely prefer it over "Basket B has half again as many apples as Basket A", but I'd probably say "Basket B has 50% more apples than Basket A" or "Basket B has one-and-a-half times as many apples as Basket A" instead